# Min Role Conversion

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, 2019

I've created a **MEDIUM NON-HA MinRole Farm (4 servers)** Farm

- Application (Central Admin)
- Front-end (WFE 1)
- Distributed Cache
- Search

I've been running into some issues that point to the WFE being overloaded recently and was wondering if I could convert my

- Distributed Cache to Front-end with Distributed Cache
  or the

or the

- Front-end to Front-end with Distributed Cache and Distributed Cache to Front-end with Distributed Cache

[image]

Would this make a difference in general performance? And is it as easy as switching the role in Central Admin?

Any advice is greatly apricated.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have a load balancer in front of your FEs, yes I think that would be the right approach -- with a farm that otherwise has no high availability, there's no reason to separate out DC onto a dedicated server as your environment isn't large enough to call for it.

You could make your farm highly available by making the backends App + Search, though you'd need to modify the Search topology via PowerShell.

And if your SQL Server isn't highly available, you'll want to fix that, too.

Comment: Thanks. that does make sense. Out of experience is it that simple to just switch the DC to a WFE with DC?
And in regards to a highly available SQL server. How would i got about finding out if I have one?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, DC -> DC+FE is easy. You need a load balancer in front of your two FEs and point your A/CNAMEs at the VIP. For SQL, ask your DBA if you have Mirroring or AlwaysOn Availability Groups set up and validate SharePoint is configured appropriately. If not, follow https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/move-all-databases#to-point-the-web-application-to-the-new-database-server-by-setting-up-sql-server-connection-aliases.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll check with them.

Comment: So I just spoke to our DBA, and he said that a load balancer is not an option at the moment. Let me ask you this. Is a custom role advice? what if i make my DC a custom role and enable a few extra services to offload the FE?